# Scrum, but with no testing or documentation

Tags: testing, scrum

What do you do when you join a team that says they use Scrum, but only use it as a time-management tool and not the whole process?
How can I reinstate back testing and documentation?

I was thinking to start off with adding user stories specifically for testing and documenting.
Perhaps someone else has more experience with this then I do about this as I am sure its not that uncommon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the issue that they don't have any documentation and tests, or that they aren't implementing the entire Scrum methodology?  Those are 2 very different problems in my mind.

I would much prefer an organization that has taken the time and effort to find and fit a development process that matches their development style as opposed to mandating down from on high the one true process.  So I would not be concerned at all if they were using a process that they called Scrum but that didn't meet all the "official" guidelines.  Try to determine why the process is the way it is.  Chances are that if they have taken the time to tailor it, the team will be receptive to your ideas, especially if you have taken the time to determine why things are the way they are.  If you simply approach it as "this isn't Scrum and so isn't right", you will probably not make much headway, but by being pragmatic about the benefits you can likely make some substantial improvements.

Alternatively, if they aren't doing testing and don't have any documentation I would consider that a fairly bad sign.  And by documentation I am taking the minimalist view here - a list of features, bug tracking, etc. - I would be very concerned by the absence of these items, less concerned by the absence of items higher up the abstraction list.  In the absence of support from management, I would suggest you lead by example.  Take it on yourself to setup a simple bug tracking system (there are several - in a pinch, simple text lists in a central location work as well).  Don't declare your features complete until someone else has tested it.  This can be as simple as walking over to another developer and asking them to try it in front of you.  If someone claims a feature is complete, take a few minutes to familiarize yourself with it.  If you find a bug, politely mention it to the responsible developer.  Slowly build an environment where the team can see the benefits of running tests and tracking features and bugs.

Most teams operate in this manner simply because of a mistaken belief that they don't have time to "do it right", or that they will get to it later.  Often this will occur when a simple proof-of-concept done by a developer or two as a side-project turns into a full-on development effort.  By showing that it can actually save time and effort, and reducing the initial costs to the rest of the team, you will often find that it becomes ingrained as part of the process without ever actually being officially endorsed or accepted.

If you have management support it will make it much easier, but always be careful to make sure that the team is receptive to the changes.  This may mean it takes longer than you want, but so be it,  without the team's support any mandated process will fail at the first sign of pressure, which is when you need the process the most.

*Disclaimer - On my last project I spearheaded the movement to tailor the SCRUM process to fit our environment.  The "official" process was simply untenable for our client, but it was still an invaluable guide in tailoring our process.

Answer (score 2):

The key to scrum is that a task be identifiable as "done" before it can be classed as done. How does you company assess whether something is done without reviewing documentation and tests?

Perhaps they have an unusual, but valid, way of doing it. Or perhaps they have missed the point of "done tasks". I'd suggest you start by asking them how they measure down and whether it could be improved. Then suggest documentation and testing as the way of improving the process.

Answer (score 2):

Note that neither testing nor documentation are in fact part of Scrum. Scrum is a pure project management approach - the required engineering practices, like the ones you mention, are supposed to "emerge" during the project. And most specifically, they are supposed to be identified during the heartbeat retrospectives that you do at the end of every sprint. Are you doing those? Can you bring up your concerns there - and are they actually the biggest concerns the team has?

Answer (score 0):

"adding user stories specifically for testing and documenting"

While meta-user stories might make sense in some circles, it rarely works out well.  Software folks rarely cope well with meta-user stories, they either don't get the idea that they can change their own processes by writing a story, or -- more typically -- they engineer the meta-user story to death.

When you're interviewing users, it feels like they're making the user story up.  Certainly, you're making it up as you listen to them and try to capture it.

When an IT organization tries to make up its own user stories about how IT should work, the process falls apart.  Until the organization has done the thing (testing, for example) a bunch of times manually, they're not really qualified to write user stories.  Then, after they've done it, they don't need software development processes, they'll just automate the important bits a little at a time.

I think change has to come from a less formal direction.  Actually balking at calling something "done" that hasn't been tested is a good starting point.

IT doesn't do things unless forced.  So, meet the users and find out why they're not requiring testing.  Coach them to require testing.  Tell them the consequences and the words to use.

A lot can go wrong in an organization to lead to poor processes.  It's important to know what's wrong, and create a demand for change.  The best possible thing is to have your boss complaining that you're not fixing it, rather than you suggesting that perhaps it would be good to fix it.

[It doesn't *feel* right when your boss demands you fix the process, but it's about the only way change will happen.]